# Can you control the re-renders of a functional react component based on state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-functional-component

I have a basic e-commerce app for practice. There's a functional component called "Shop" which has two states:

```
[products, setProducts] = useState([10ProductObjects])
and [cart, setCart] = useState([])
```

On the first render cycle, the 10 products are loaded and each `Product` component has an "add to cart" button that adds a product to the cart array.
When I click the button, the cart array gets populated and its length is displayed. However, doing so re-renders the 10 products again even though nothing has been changed on them.

Now as I see it since one of the states changes i.e. the cart array, the whole `Shop` component is rendered again. Which in turn renders its child components, including those which were not changed.

I've tried to use `React.memo` but it doesn't help since no props are being changed on "Shop", rather the state is changing. I've also used the `useMemo` hook and it had some interesting results.

Using the products array as a dependency solves the extra re-rendering problem, but the new products are not added to the cart anymore. Using both `[products, cart]` as the dependencies works but brings back the original problem.

I know it could be done using `shouldComponentUpdate` but I need that kind of flexibility in functional components.

N.B: This is my first ever question and I'm all ears for any kind of feedback.

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import fakeData from '../../fakeData';
import Product from '../Product/Product';

const Shop = () => {
console.log('[Shop.js] rendered')
const first10 = fakeData.slice(0, 10);
const [products, setProducts] = useState(first10);
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);


const addProductHandler = (product) => {
    console.log(cart, product);
    const newCart = [...cart, product];
    console.log(newCart); 
    setCart(newCart);
    
}
let productsOnScreen = useMemo(() => {
    return products.map( prod => {
        return  <Product product={prod} addProductHandler={addProductHandler} />
    });
}, [products])

 
return (
    <div className="shop-container">
        <div className="product-container">
            {productsOnScreen}
        </div>
        <div className="cart-container">
            <h3>this is cart</h3>
            <h5>Order Summary: {cart.length}</h5>
    </div>
    </div>
);
};

export default Shop;
```

Comment: Don't prematurely optimize. Is there a specific reason you want to avoid re-renders? "Extra" renders should never be a problem 99% of the time if you are managing your state and effects correctly. React is very well optimized, and you are extremely unlikely to run into performance issues except in rare cases (this is not one of them).

Comment: In this particular scenario, neither the product listings are being updated nor the individual products are changed in any way. So why should they be re-rendered? And yes I'm kind of prematurely optimizing, or rather learning to optimize because it will be easier for me to grasp the theory in simple applications like this one. 

Thanks for commenting.

Comment: It does not matter if they re-render even if their state hasn't changed. That is totally fine and normal and happens all the time. As long as the render function properly transforms state and props into the correct rendered output, it does not matter one bit. Worry more about your state, props, and effects then the # of times things are "re-rendered", it does not matter 99% of the time. If you have any logic that depends on the number of rerenders that have occurred, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: It is totally fine and expected that child components would re-render when their containing parent re-renders. This is how React works.

Comment: I understand the point you're trying to make. But I'll wait to see if I get some different perceptions to the problem and edit the post then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memoize `addProductHandler` with [`React.useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) so that the reference to it does not change between renders:

```
const addProductHandler = React.useCallback((product) => {
    setCart(oldCart => {
        return [...oldCart, product];
    });
}, [setCart]);
```

Then, memoize `<Product>` with [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo). You didn't post your code for that component but it would look something like this:

```
export const Product = React.memo((props) => {
  // normal functional component stuff

  return <>product component or whatever</>;
});
```

These are both necessary for a component to avoid unnecessary rerenders. Why?

1. `React.useCallback` allows for comparison-by-reference to work for a callback function between renders. This does not work if you declare the callback function *every* render, as you have currently.
2. `React.memo` wraps a component to enable it to render or *not* render depending on a shallow comparison of its props. React components do NOT do this by default, you have to explicitly enable it with `React.memo`.

As the docs mention:

> This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.

In other words, you should only use this as a performance optimization if you are experiencing slowdowns, NOT to prevent renders for any other reason, and ONLY if you are *actually* experiencing performance issues.

If this doesn't work, it's likely that one of your `<Product>` props is *still* changing (in the context of shallow comparison-by-reference) between renders. Keep playing with and memoizing props until you figure out which ones are changing between renders. One way to test this is a simple `React.useEffect` (for debug purposes only) inside of `<Product>` which will alert you when a prop has changed:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('product prop changed');
}, [product]);

React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log('addProductHandler prop changed');
}, [addProductHandler]);

// etc...
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works like a charm. I will dig into React.useCallback to understand it bit better. But I will keep the documentation's quoted part in mind.